# Returning an image as an array

Tags: php, image-resizing

I'm trying to resize an image in PHP if an uploaded image is too big. I've created a function that should resize the file, and then (hopefully) return an array -- except it isn't working :(

```
private function _resizeImage($image, $width = 780, $height = 780) {

    $imgDetails = GetImageSize($image["tmp_name"]);

    // Content type
    //header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    //header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=resized-$image");

    // Get dimensions
    $width_orig = $imgDetails['0'];
    $height_orig = $imgDetails['1'];

    $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

    if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
       $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
    } else {
       $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
    }

    // Resample
    switch ( $imgDetails['2'] ) 
    {
      case 1: $newImage = imagecreatefromgif($image["tmp_name"]); break;
      case 2: $newImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($image["tmp_name"]); break;
      case 3: $newImage = imagecreatefrompng($image["tmp_name"]); break;
      default: trigger_error('Unsupported filetype!', E_USER_WARNING);  break;
    }

    if (!$newImage) {
        // We get errors from PHP's ImageCreate functions...
        // So let's echo back the contents of the actual image.
        readfile ($image);
    } else {
        // Create the resized image destination
        $thumb = @ImageCreateTrueColor ($width, $height);
        // Copy from image source, resize it, and paste to image destination
        @ImageCopyResampled ($thumb, $newImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
        // Output resized image
        //ImageJPEG ($thumb);
    }

    // Output
    $newFile = imagejpeg($thumb, null, 100);
    return $newFile;
}
```

Which is called by:

```
if($imgDetails['0'] > 780 || $imgDetails['1'] < 780) {
    $file = $this->_resizeImage($file); // Resize image if bigger than 780x780
}
```

But I'm not getting an object back, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) returns boolean. Not an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Seain mentioned in comment, imagejpeg returns a bool value.

```
bool imagejpeg ( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality ]] )

Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
```

[imagejpeg reference on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)

Also, you have NULL as the second parameter which will output the image as a raw image stream. If you want to save the image to file somewhere you need to provide a filename for this parameter.

Another note - you should call `imagedestroy($newImage);` to free up memory you allocated when you created the image from gif/jpeg/png. Do this after you call `imagejpeg`.

Also I recommend that you not suppress your errors using the `@` operator. Instead try logging those errors to the error log. The suppression will make it harder to debug your code and if there is a critical error you suppress it will kill your script entirely with no indication as to why. Error logs help.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. How can I create a $_FILES object for the new image? Should I just build the array by hand? And what do I run `imagedestroy` on? The new filename...?

Comment: Call `imagedestroy` on `$newImage` because `$newImage` is the image resource identifier that you created when you called `imagecreatefromjpeg`,`imagecreatefrompng` or `imagecreatefromgif`.

Comment: You don't add anything to the `$_FILES` superglobal, you get the filename it gives for the upload, if the image is too big you resize it and save that back to file and pass that filename instead to the next step of your PHP app. So whatever function gets called next should take a filename/path as a parameter and you can either give it the original from `$_FILES` OR the new file path you created when you resized the image. Hope that helps. Try to avoid modifying the content of `$_FILES` if possible.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I will try to avoid modifying $_FILES -- I meant a $_FILES-like object. E.g. $newImage["name"], $newImage["type"], $newImage["size"], etc. To be honest, I'm not sure how to reference the image created by `imagejpeg` -- all I have is a filename :(

Comment: Forget it! I figured it all out! Thanks for your help!